# Appending args and code to an inherited method in python2?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm inheriting a class with an **init** method already set.
I'd like to add an arg to this method, as well as a few lines of code.
I suspect that I can use super to do this, but am not quite sure how and the examples I've found don't always make sense to me.

Example code AND EXPLANATION:
The bot module has 2 classes: Bot, and BotStreamListener
BotStreamListener inherits from tweepy.StreamListener, which already has **init** defined
I need to append an arg and some code to this classmethod so that methods in the BotStreamListener class know the instantiated instance of the Bot class. (in the example below, it's mybot).

...

```
def main():

    try:
        me = api.me()
        print "Starting userstream for %s ( %s )" %(me.name, me.screen_name)
        mybot = bot.bot(api)
        #What it looks like now
        stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, bot.BotStreamListener(api))

        #What i would like it to be able to handle
        stream = tweepy.Stream(auth, bot.BotStreamListener(api, mybot))
```

In short, I would like to add a few more args and some code to an inherited **init** classmethod, without redefining the method.
I'm using python 2.7, any help is apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with tweepy other than knowing what it is, but this should get you started:

```
# bot.py
class BotStreamListener(StreamListener):
    def __init__(api, bot):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(api)
        # Do your stuff
        self.bot = bot
        # Do more of your stuff

mybot = bot.bot(api)
bsl = BotStreamListener(api, mybot)
```

Comment: Wow, that worked really well. For others who may have this problem, here's the resulting code: –  

    class BotStreamListener(StreamListener):
        """Class that handles tweepy streaming events.
    E.g: on_connect, on_disconnect, on_status, on_direct_message, etc.
    """

        def __init__(self, api, bot):
            # Adding a bot arg and code to store it in the instantiated class
            super(self.__class__, self).__init__(api)
            self.bot = bot